# play youtube video on click custom button

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I do have following code where i want to play youtube video when button is clicked.

I have iframe code for youtube.

```
<script>

            var player = document.getElementById("myplayer");

            //Create a simple function and check if player exists
            function play() {
                if(player) {
                    player.playVideo();
                }
            }


 </script>


<iframe id="myplayer" width="500" height="500" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/C-VoyCDUvr0?rel=0&wmode=Opaque&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<a href="#" onclick="play()">Play Youtube Video</a>
```

But it does not play when i click on button / link

I put script code in head part of html and iframe and anchor link in body part of html.

[image]

Am i missing anything?

Comment: Check your javascript console first for errors and see if those reveal anything?

Comment: it says following: ReferenceError: player is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

if(player) {

Comment: i included javascript file: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script> in header.

Comment: You can fetch the preview image, display it, then when your button is clicked, replace the image with the iframe where autoplay is set to true. Example of this type of structure in action: https://merkd.com/teams/ExtraordinaryKillers Stream & Highlights 

If you would like to use this method let me know and I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here I gave the example of two players:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="divPlayer1"></div>

<div id="divPlayer2"></div>

    <script>
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player1;
      var player2;
     function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player1 = new YT.Player('divPlayer1', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'iZYIsJ9i5yE',});

    player2 = new YT.Player('divPlayer2', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'J7rKAKipj8s',});

      }
function play1() { 
        player1.playVideo();
      }
function play2() { 
        player2.playVideo();
      }
  </script>

<a href="#" onclick="play1()">Play Youtube Video1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="play2()"> Play Youtube Video2</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There probably is no `iframe#myplayer` yet when your script is run. Move the definition of `player` inside the function like this:

```
function play() {
    var player = document.getElementById("myplayer"); // Moved here
    if(player) {
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

That should work.

**Edit**: That latter link seems to suggest you do this instead:

```
var player; // Might not be necessary

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    player = document.getElementById("myplayer");
}

function play() { 
    if(player) {
        player.playVideo();
    }
}
```

Comment: no mate, its not working. Do i need to add any youtube javascript library, though i added: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script> I am seeing this docs now: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingReference

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the second link's contents

Comment: no man, still no hope, i think i missing something? but if dont use var player then javascript console shows 'player is not defined' error

Comment: is it anyhthing worng in my iframe code? can smeone chekc plz:  <iframe id="myplayer" width="500" height="500" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/C-VoyCDUvr0?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function toggleVideo(state) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("myplayer").contentWindow;
        func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
        iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<!-- popup and contents -->
<iframe id="myplayer" width="500" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C-VoyCDUvr0?enablejsapi=1"
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="toggleVideo();">Play Youtube Video</a>
```

Comment: does your code works in your browser? did u inclue any youtube javascript file in header? i put ur code but it doesnot play the video!!! where i am missing?

Comment: please add this "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api">
    </script>" in header tag

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code with one play. Should be altered only by videoId: 'iZYIsJ9i5yE' whity our videoId in youtube:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="player"></div>

      <script>
          var tag = document.createElement('script');

          tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

          var player1;
         function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            player1 = new YT.Player('player', {
              height: '390',
              width: '640',
              videoId: 'iZYIsJ9i5yE',});
          }
         function play1() { 
            player1.playVideo();
          }

         </script>

      <a href="#" onclick="play1()">Play Youtube Video</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this iframe and change your youtube link. I hope it will work surely. It is working on my website.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2XXzYCfBiAg" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen style="width:100%; height:445px; padding:0; left:25%"></iframe>
```